# Break out of a list of functions in GPIO stepper-motor control

Tags: python, concurrency, raspberry-pi

I want to add a switch to my raspberry pi which acts as an emergency stop switch. But it should not shut down the PI or end the whole program. It should only stop the Motor and drive it back to the starting point. So if a specified GPIO receive a signal from the switch the list of functions should break immediately.

```py
def A2Fahrt():
    GUIlock()            # locks the GUI
    StepperForwards()    # moves a stepper motor forwards until the a switch is triggered
    StepperBackwards()   # moves a stepper motor backwards until the a switch is triggered
    GUIunlock()          # unlocks the GUI
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Edit:

```
def StepperForwards():
GPIO.output(A2M2, False)
GPIO.output(A2M, True)
GPIO.output(A2D, True)
pi.hardware_PWM(A2S, 1000, 500000) 
time.sleep(0.1)
pi.hardware_PWM(A2S, 1800, 500000) 
time.sleep(0.75)
GPIO.output(A2M, False)
GPIO.output(A2M2, True)
pi.hardware_PWM(A2S, 450, 500000)  
time.sleep(0.25)
while True:
    if (GPIO.input(1) == False):
            pi.hardware_PWM(A2S, 550,500000)         
    else:
        #pi.hardware_PWM(A2S,0,0) 
        #time.sleep(0.2)
        pi.hardware_PWM(A2S, 25, 250000) 
        time.sleep(2) 
        #pi.hardware_PWM(A2S,0,0) 
        #time.sleep(0.5)
        break
```

Comment: did you write `StepperForwards()`? would it be possible to add code inside it to also check for the emergency stop?

Comment: You're looking to have an inner loop that cycles through the stepper functions (which run for a limited time or distance, then yield/suspend back to the loop). This is called ***[tag:concurrency]*** It doesn't necessarily have to involve multiple threads (and in the case of precise motor control it almost surely shouldn't).

Comment: I add the code from the StepperForwards function.

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by [clicking on the big gray check button on its left side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer). If you wish you can also upvote helpful answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to solve this would be with multithreading. Create one thread that moves the motor, and another one that checks to see if the emergency switch is pressed.

Another one would be to have a while loop checking if a switch is pressed and run the function if it triggers.

However I'm not sure how you've written the main part of the program if you can, could you expand a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to have an inner loop that cycles through the stepper functions (which run for a limited time or distance, then yield/suspend back to the loop). This is called **[concurrency](/questions/tagged/concurrency)**.

- It doesn't necessarily have to involve multiple threads (and in the case of precise motor control it perhaps shouldn't), except...
- **It's basically a cardinal sin (antipattern) in concurrency to run *anything* other than the GUI off the GUI thread, especially anything latency-sensitive or precise like motor control or anything else real-time**

It's a problem that your functions `StepperForwards/Backwards` run perpetually until a switch is triggered, so either rewrite them, use different (concurrency-aware) versions which run for a defined time or a defined distance (number of steps), see code below, or else (undesriable fallback) use a second thread to poll user I/O (this is really undesirable for precise motor control, because ~20ms latency in switching threads or disabling the motor will translate into 20ms x velocity of positional uncertainty, which is baaad).

As to the GUI:

- you need have a very fast (preferably non-blocking) `UserKillSwitch()` function, so you can poll it.
- Note that we poll the user kill-switch *before* we unlock the GUI, which can potentially cause an 'event storm' of mouseovers, focus changes, rendering, redraws...
- GUIs (some more than others) are notorious for that sort of 'event storm'. It's really a bad idea to run the motor on the same thread as the GUI.

Code:

```
# Inner loop
while True:
    GUIlock()            # locks the GUI
    StepperForwardsConcurrencyAware()    # moves a stepper motor forwards until the a switch is triggered
    StepperBackwardsConcurrencyAware()   # moves a stepper motor backwards until the a switch is triggered

    # Note that we poll the user kill-switch *before* we unlock the GUI, which can potentially cause an 'event storm' of mouseovers, focus changes, rendering, redraws...
    if UserKillSwitch():
        break

    # only now finally unlock the GUI
    GUIunlock()
```

Comment: I tried it like this before with:" if GPIO.input(MBE2) == False):     break"   But it only breaks after the GUIunlock() function. If I don`t press the switch the complete function starts from the beginning